# Electrical outlet popping sound when plugging in anything?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

So a lot of the questions asked about outlets here indicate that the circuit breaker trips when the outlet pops, but mine does not.

When I connect even low power stuff like my HomePod or phone charger to most outlets, nothing happens: they just plug in like normal. But with a couple of outlets in my office there is a visible pop/spark when I plug anything in. I thought just buying a new outlet would solve the issue, but it did not which concerns me. One thing to note: I did not adjust the wiring on the outlet. Right now I’m not plugging anything into it. Am I right to be concerned? Any thoughts on what the issue could be?

Comment: What things are you plugging in?

Comment: You could use an extension cord for a test. If the popping doesn't happen, does happen still at the outlet location, or does happen at the end of the cord where the device is plugged in will give some insight to possible causes.

Comment: Power supplies many times do draw a fair amount of current on start and you may notice an arc that is normal. I have a friend that was bothered by it so much I ended putting his receptacle on a switch so he would not see the arc, turn the switch off plug in and turn the switch on. It was a supply that drew 5 amps at 19 or 21v it may be normal and you are like him and just notice the small arc when plugging in a device.

Comment: could be static electricity; does that part of the office have a rug?

Comment: Harper - mainly things in the OP, my HomePod, a Samsung wireless charging plate, stuff I’ve plugged into other outlets with no issue. 

Greg - I had a smart plug and it didn’t seem to cause any sparking when I plugged it in and then subsequently when I plugged in a charger it was fine.

Comment: Dan - this may be the cause, there is a rug that I roll around on with my chair and moved furniture across to accommodate the plug. I tried this time, being careful to discharge my static on a door knob and avoid the rug and everything plugged in normally. Can static really cause that much of a reaction?

Comment: Ed - yeah, I would say so as well if I hadn’t plugged other stuff into it. Is it possible that it shares a circuit with an appliance or something under load?